# Why does the following appear when I start the Rails server instead of something functional?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
< %= render :partial => "message_form" %> < %= render :partial => @posts %>
```

What is displayed above is the code I had written down in index.html.erb, but it is also displaying on my local host page as well.  Maybe it's a routing issue?

I am following this guide to building a mockup Twitter:
http://www.noupe.com/ajax/create-a-simple-twitter-app.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not supposed to be a space in between the < and the %:

```
<%= render :partial => "message_form" %> <%= render :partial => @posts %>
```